# I have tried everything I can but my website won't work or be responsive on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, responsive-images

I am having a lot of issues with making my website work correctly on iPhones. The background isn't scaling down at all on my site. I have used the following HTML...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
```

And CSS..

```
background: url('../images/FRONT_1_copy.jpg') 50% 0 repeat-y scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

If anyone can help me that would be great. It works on my Googple Pixel 3a XL ok and other android devices I have used too.

Thank you

Comment: try background-size:contain;

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that but still isn't working.

Comment: I tried your code in a BODY tag and a plain HTML page and it scales down the background as my screen gets smaller.  I tried it on my iPhone 6s and same result.

Comment: how big your image is? and look here if it might help!? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=50%25%2050%25

Comment: The image is the same as a bootstrap template I am using to cross-reference the code. That template works on iPhone but mine still does not. I have a body tag in the code as well. So frustrating lol